# How to convert stored ip in database to ip2long

Tags: php, mysql

I need to convert my stored ip's in database to ip2long

ip's are stored as usual like `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` I want to convert these values in ip2long

How should I do it, every thing is online I cant put anything offline, how should I safely make changes.

I know this way

```
$query ="SELECT id,ip from table";
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $ip2long=ip2long($row['ip']);
    $id=$row['id'];
    $update="UPDATE table SET ip='$ip2long' WHERE id='$id'";
}
```

But this is not a good approach for more than 10 million rows

Please suggest any possible way to do it quickly.

Thanks

Comment: extract the 2 columns out to a csv. Create an app in c# or java to read the file and write out the 3 columns (well really just 2) out to a second csv. Then LOAD DATA from infile that second csv into some stub table.. Which contains, by the way, the id plus your new string. Then do a "update with a join" pattern back to your real table

Comment: While there is nothing wrong with Drews answer above, personally I would go with a shell script and would do it in IP groups. This way if something goes wrong you do not need to re-start from the beginning. 10 million records is going to take time no matter what you do. You need to think about how to recover from an error quickly and a PHP loop ain't going to work well on that size of data.

Comment: There is a function inside mysql that will convert IP addresses to integers, INET_ATON(). Just update a column with that. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton

Comment: Drew's answer is correct... but, why are you storing 10M IP ?

Comment: @HalayemAnis Its the stats of user using my website, I can't mess with that.

Comment: @Lucas will doing `UPDATE table  SET ip=INET_ATON(ip)` work.

Comment: That would be the simplest option- you may want to create a separate column or table but that function will convert correctly formatted ips into integers

Comment: Just a thought, if you were to save that into an integer column make sure it is unsigned, or a bigint

Comment: @Lucas Ok,I'll try that in separate unsigned column.

Answer (score 0):

if i am doing this,

**1-** i would create a new column

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD ip_long bigint(20) unsigned;
```

**2-** execute the PHP code to convert ip -> iplong
and update(set) the long-value in the new column

```
$query ="SELECT id,ip from table";
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $ip2long=ip2long($row['ip']);
    $id=$row['id'];
    $update="UPDATE table SET ip_long='$ip2long' WHERE id='$id'";
}
echo "conversion completed";
```

**3.1** make sure your site is ready to handle IP address as LONG: prepare the mechanism you will use to switch to using new value (long), it could be comment-out a few lines , replace a library file that contains some methods ... etc

**3.2**- drop old column **ip**, and rename new column **ip_long** to **ip**

```
ALTER TABLE table_name DROP COLUMN ip;
ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE ip_long ip bigint(20) unsigned;
```

**3.2 hint: for double safety** you can just rename old column (ip) to something else (ip_old) and keep, in case the process did not success in any stage, or you needed to revert to regular IP format for any reason, you can exeucte below statement to rename the column:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE ip ip_old varchar(15); --replace varchar(15) with actual column definition ex: varchar(15) not null... etc.
```

when you are sure the process is OK and you dont need old ip any more, just drop it

```
ALTER TABLE table_name DROP COLUMN ip_old;
```

**Note:** it's recommended to execute last 2 statements on the same PHP page
or even on a shell session (if possible) to make sure no errors pops for users
,ex: column not found 'ip'